# What is the correct place/bundle to place this action

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony

Say I have a `CoreBundle`, which has an entity called `Event`. In the `CoreBundle`, events can e.g. be shown (`showAction`). I also have a `BackendBundle`. The event's `deleteAction` can only be triggered from the backend. However, the `deleteAction` belongs to an entity that is defined in the `CoreBundle`. Both the `CoreBundle` and the `BackendBundle` have an `EventController`.

The question is: Should the `deleteAction` be placed in the `BackendBundle`'s `EventController` or in the `CoreBundle`'s `EventController`?

P.s. I know both will work, but this is more somewhat of a phylosophical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a `BackendBundle` with an `EventController` and a `deleteAction`. This deleteAction may call a specific handler (or manager or whatever) inside the `CoreBundle`, but I would keep the controller code inside the BackendBundle.

First, it makes it easy to follow the code without switching bundles. I can see that the request comes in, that either the entity is deleted or that some manager is called and that a redirect is send or a template is rendered.

Second, and way more important, is that if you introduce another bundle which has a deleteAction for the backend, you can either have different ways of handling them (one inside it's own bundle and one inside the `CoreBundle`) or you have to name them different and create a big mess.

In generell, I stick to the rule to have the controller inside the same bundle where the route and the view lives and only share the model. In case of a CoreBundle, I handle deletion with a manager between the controller and the model. In your case the `deleteAction` would get a `EventManager` service and call a delete with either the object or an id (depending on my needs). This way the code executed to delete an event is in one place and can be changed easily.

Comment: I spoke to some people in the meantime, and everyone concurs. Controllers accompany views, and if a specific action can only be done from a view within the backend, we should move the deleteAction "close" to that view

Comment: Sgoettshkes you litterally steal words from my mouth. Great answer. +1